# Scala collection for grouping while maintaining order

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have something like this

```
case class Job(workId: Int, users: List[String])
val jobs = IndexedSeq(Job(1, List("a", "b")), Job(2, List("b", "c")), Job(3, List("a", "c" )), Job(4, List("d", "b")))
```

I want to convert this to something like:

```
Map(c -> Vector(2, 3), a -> Vector(1, 3), d -> Vector(4), b -> Vector(1, 2, 4))
```

I basically want to maintain the order of Job.workId in the original sequence. So since the Job with workId 1 comes before the job with workId 3, a's entry in the map has JobId 1 before JobId 3.

I couldn't find a straight forward way of doing this. Right now I have:

```
((for (job <- jobs;
   user <- job.users)
   yield { (user, job.work) }) groupBy { tuple => tuple._1 }) map { tuple => (tuple._1 -> (tuple._2 map { _._2 })) }
```

This first creates:

```
Map(c -> Vector((c,2), (c,3)), a -> Vector((a,1), (a,3)), d -> Vector((d,4)), b -> Vector((b,1), (b,2), (b,4)))
```

and then transforms it to:

```
Map(c -> Vector(2, 3), a -> Vector(1, 3), d -> Vector(4), b -> Vector(1, 2, 4))
```

This seems rather verbose. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this while preserving the order. Also I don't like that it needs to iterate over the initial Sequence multiple times.

I have another lengthier solution:

```
val mapping =  scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, IndexedSeq[Int]]()

 for (job <- jobs;
       user <- job.users)
   yield{
     if (mapping.contains(user)) {
       val entry = mapping(user)
       mapping.put(user, entry :+ job.work)
     } else {
       mapping += user -> mutable.IndexedSeq(job.work)
     }
  }
```

mapping now is:

```
Map(c -> ArrayBuffer(2, 3), a -> ArrayBuffer(1, 3), d -> ArrayBuffer(4), b -> ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 4))
```

This shares the initial for comprehensions but does not need the extra iterations that come from using groupBy and then map.

Is there a more idiomatic and concise way of doing this with the standard collection methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with just about all questions with List processing, this is solvable with a fold!

```
(for {
  job <- jobs.view;
  user <- job.users
} yield (job, user)).foldLeft (Map[String, Vector[Int]]()) { case (acc, (a,b)) =>
  acc + (b -> (acc.getOrElse(b, Vector()) :+ a.workId))
}
```

Unfortunately, Scala's type inferencer is not capable of determining the type of the initial 'Map', so you have to specify it explicitly.

Using the 'view' method on the initial collection makes this lazy, and will only perform a single pass through the initial list.

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up writing a little performance test with a few different ways of doing this. The foldLeft method performed better than the imperative method that I had before. I modified the imperative method to use a view and then run a foreach on the results. Finally I also had a method that just used a nested foreach. The nested foreach performed the best but the fold method was very close. The imperative method performed the worse and the imperative with a view modification performed only slightly better.

Comment: I think I'll end up using Guava's ArrayListMultimap. It has the best performance and also maintains the order of insertion unlike Scala's multimap.